# 2D struct array member variable with varying sizes

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

So I've got a class that I'm generalizing into a base class. One of the member variables is a 2D array of a struct.

```
struct SomeType
{
...
}
```

and then in the class's header:

```
SomeType member_variable_ [SIZE_ONE][SIZE_TWO];
```

But, in my situation, `SIZE_TWO` needs to be set when the class is initialized because it's going to be different depending on what's using this.  What's the best way to have a 2D struct array with a size that's not yet set as a member variable?

Comment: does it have to be an array? why not use the Vector class?

Comment: When you say that you need a different size on "initialization", what do you mean by that? Do you need the size to be different at run-time or at compile-time? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to solve it is to not use C-style arrays at all, but to use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Or possibly an [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) of vectors:

```
std::array<std::vector<SomeType>, SIZE_ONE> member_variable_;
```

Now you can easily insert as many (or as few) `SomeType` objects as needed, and still use the array-indexing syntax:

```
member_variable_[some_index][some_other_index]
```

---

To set a fixed size at runtime for the "second" Dimension, you can do something like this in the constructor:

```
for (auto& v : member_variable_)
    v = std::vector<SomeType>(the_runtime_size);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a template:

```
template<unsigned SIZE_TWO>
class theClass
{
     SomeType member_variable_ [SIZE_ONE][SIZE_TWO];
```

`SIZE_TWO` will be set when you instantiate the class.

```
theClass<5> tc; //member_variable_ [SIZE_ONE][5];
```

You could also use containers like `std::vector` or `std::array`.